# GridView scroll down and up when click on buttons?

Tags: android

I have a View with GridView and two Buttons(up and down) in it.Here when we click on down button  gridview will be scroll down and click on up button gridview will scroll up.Is there any chance to do that.Please any one give guidance(or tutorial) to do that.please help me

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate the position of first image to be displayed and set that position in gridview using `smoothScrollToPosition()` if using api 8 or higher `gridview.scrollTo(x, y)` if using lower api

**Step-1** get the first and last image position from greed view

**Step-2** When user clicks down button stroe the selected position as `last visible image position +1` When user clicks up button store the selected position as `first visible image position -1`
**Step-3** set the image selection using and scroll the gridview by passing x and y co-ordinate of the image using `gridview.scrollTo(x, y)` for lower api and using `smoothScrollToPosition(position)` for api 8 or higher

Comment: i added code mGrid.smoothScrollToPosition(3).it is showing error.i am using api 7.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into `smoothScrollToOffset(int offset)` and `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`, both of which are GridView functions.

I would recommend using `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)` since it takes as a parameter the position (in your adapter) of the view you want to scroll to. Presumably, you would know the position in your adapter of the place you want to scroll to.

Look here for reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Comment: thanks Alex..i added code mGrid.smoothScrollToPosition(3).it is showing error.i am using api 7.